# Как проверить пустая ли таблица в базе данных

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Добрый день.
Метод isRegister работает некорректно, результат: Одно из активити, при вызове метода isRegister выкидывает из приложения, а должно через switch(isRegister) выбирать один из активити и переходить в него.
Интересует, если метод isRegister не верный, как его оформить верно, чтобы проверять пустая таблица или нет.
Вот код:

```
class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private DBHelper dbHelper;
    DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "myDB", null, 1);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table Users ("
                + "id integer primary key autoincrement,"
                + "name text,"
                + "birthday date,"
                + "city text" + ");");
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {}

    void addAccount(String name, String city, String editTextDateParam) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        cv.put("name", name);
        cv.put("birthday", editTextDateParam);
        cv.put("city", city);
        db.insert("Users", null, cv);
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    int isRegister() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.query("Users", null, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (!c.moveToFirst()) {
            c.close();
            dbHelper.close();
            return 0;
        } else { c.close(); dbHelper.close(); return 1; }
    }
}
```

Comment: В данном случае вопрос связан с одной предметной областью.
Здесь происходит ошибка скорее всего в методы IsRegister , и вот я попросил проверить его и класс DB с целью детерменирования проблемы.

Comment: Cкорректировал, еще есть замечания?

Comment: Спасибо, прочёл.

Comment: Покажите полный текст возникающей ошибки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без текста ошибки сложно определить в чём именно проблема. Возможно в том, что в приведённом вами коде нет инициализации поля `dbHelper`. Судя по тому, что поле имеет тип включающего его класса, класс задумывался как [singleton](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)). Тогда надо добавить к нему фабричный метод и изменить конструктор:

```
class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static DBHelper dbHelper;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDB";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public static DBHelper newInstance(Context context) {
        if (dbHelper == null) {
            dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
        }
        return dbHelper;
    }
}
```

И в вызывающем коде

```
DBHelper dbHelper = DBHelper.newInstance(getApplicationContext());
switch (dbHelper.isRegister()) {
    ...
}
```

Кроме того, я вижу в методе isRegister пару неоптимальных элементов и пару стилевых недочётов:

1. вы в нём ничего в базу не пишите, но экземпляр подключения к БД получаете вызовом get**Writable**Database(), лучше заменить на [getReadableDatabase()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getReadableDatabase()).
2. Не обязательно открывать курсор, чтобы получить количество записей в таблице. можно использовать [DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#queryNumEntries%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String%29).
3. Имя метода `isRegister()` подразумевает возврат булевого значения. Если вам нужно именно количество пользователей, лучше поменять имя метода. Если нет, тип возвращаемого значения.
4. Вы сознательно опустили модификатор доступа для метода `isRegister()`? Подозреваю, что там должен быть `public`.

Итого получается:

```
public boolean isRegister() {
    try (SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase()) {
        return (DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, "Users") != 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы правы, на счет всего, что вы сделали, сейчас проверю.
Код ошибки не смог приложить, так его нет, запускал с телефона, а не с эмулятора. Сейчас проверю, спасибо.

Comment: Switch-case не работает с Boolean, так что isRegister не может применяться к Switch-case.

Comment: Я не вижу того кода, где вы используете `isRegister()`. Может быть, вам и не нужен там switch и вполне достаточно if-else. Если нужен, возвращайте int: `return DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, "Users")`.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev , спасибо большое, помогли, всё работает!
Switch-case заменил на if(!dbHelper.isRegister())

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, [примите его как решение](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).